# How to stop autocorrect input text for a PWA on mobile browser (Android and iOS)?

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, progressive-web-apps, autocorrect

On my PWA, for input, native keyboard of the phones are active. Need code for following usecases
1. How to disable autocorrect for PWA for android and iOS?
2. How to build your own keyboard without auto correct for PWA for android and iOS?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using following code with you input field inside form element :-

   autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"
2. I think making your own keyboard is not a good idea as it will take much time, if you want to have your own virtual keyboard(i hope for security reasons you are doing this) you can use open souce javascript plugins for the same.